# Shape of passed values is (1, 20), indices imply (37, 20)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

```
frame = []
for i in range(1,21):
    frame.append(sampler(i))         
 # sampler is a function which return an array of 764*36

header = ['Act_High', 'Act_Low', 'Act_Avg', 'Precip_Amt', 'Festival_Impact',
       'Val_Share', 'Variable_Disc___ValueOff__Rs',
       'Non_Discounted_Gross_Revenue__Rs__', 'Fixed_Disc___ValueOff__Rs',
       'Total_Volume__No__', 'unitMrp', 'Variable_Disc___PerOff__Rs',
       'Fixed_Disc___FOC__Rs', 'Variable_Disc___FOC__Rs',
       'Fixed_Disc___PerOff__Rs', 'Total_Volume__No__rmean',
       'Non_Discounted_Gross_Revenue__Rs__rmean', 'Total_Volume__No__rmax',
       'Non_Discounted_Gross_Revenue__Rs__rmax', 'Total_Volume__No__rmin',
       'Non_Discounted_Gross_Revenue__Rs__rmin', 'Total_Volume__No__rstd',
       'Non_Discounted_Gross_Revenue__Rs__rstd', 'Total_Volume__No__rymean',
       'Non_Discounted_Gross_Revenue__Rs__rymean', 'Apr', 'Aug', 'Dec',
       'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'Mar', 'May', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep']


frame = np.nan_to_num(frame)
frame = pd.DataFrame(frame, columns = header)





ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 20), indices imply (37, 20)
```

Comment: what does sampler does?

Comment: does sampler definitely do what you think it does?  what does frame look like after the for loop?

Comment: sampler(1).shape ->  (767, 37)

Comment: the problem is i think it's creating 3d array and I need to convert it into 2d .. but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Okay, hi.

I am trying to rebuild you environment a little bit to help you with the problem. I hope I understand correctly that `sampler(i=1)` returns an array from the first position with the shape of (767, 37).

Let's make a dummy function out of all this:

```
def sampler(i):
 a = np.empty((21, 764, 36))
 return a[i]
```

So, if I define `sampler(i=1).shape` it returns an array of a shape (767, 37)!

Then, if I append a list called **frame** with 20 arrays (as you do in a loop), it is still a 1-d input for a DataFrame which is inappropriate, because `pd.DataFrame(data=data, ...)` requires 2-d input. Your **frame** is neither 3-d input nor 2-d input as ValueError states.

Let's consider an example:

```
a = sampler(i=1)
a.shape  # (767, 37)
b = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=header)
```

It will create a DataFrame where each columns is labeled accordingly. In your case, though, you try to label 20 elements of **frame**, which is also a 1-d list, with 37 labels.

> You could run the following to fix the issue I suppose:

```
frame = np.nan_to_num(frame)
frame = np.array(frame)
frame = np.reshape(-1, 37)
frame = pd.DataFrame(frame, columns=header)
```

I'm not totally sure whether it will help because I don't know what you really want to get from appending that **frame** list.
If you elaborated more thoroughly on your question, maybe I could help.

E.